# How do I convert JSON data to javascript object

Tags: jquery, json, object

Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong please...

I am trying to convert JSON data to Javascript Object using jQuery's parseJSON

Here is my JSON data from the lang_file.json:

```
{"lang":{  
 "welcome":"Welcome to renewals",  
 "policy_number":"Policy Number",  
 "policy_holder_dob":"Policy Holder Date of Birth"  
 }  
}
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
jQuery.getJSON("lang_file.json", function(data) {  
 var json2 = data.lang;  
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json2);  
 alert(obj.welcome);  
});
```

Jquery version : jquery-1.4.2

Thanks...

Comment: Anything wrong? Posting what errors there are would be helpful...

Comment: you do not need to reparse the json. Data parameter should hold the complete json object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to access any of that data like so already...

```
data.lang.welcome;
data.lang.policy_number;
data.lang.policy_holder_dob;
```

Or you may find it necessary to do this...

```
data.lang['policy' + someVar];
```

Comment: yeah I tried that from the start and worked, I was trying to make the call shorter, for example :: lang.policy_number :: lang being the object, thanks :)

Comment: if you're trying to make it shorter, do langObj = data.lang; then you can do langObj.policy_number

Answer (score 5):

`getJSON` parses the response for you.

You don't need to call `parseJSON` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery.getJSON("lang_file.json", function(data) {  
  alert(data.lang.welcome);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

This line easy to change the JSON data to javascript object